# Как в блок-схеме описать изменение ячейки таблицы?

Tags: блок-схема

У меня есть программа, в которой есть событие на нажатие на ячейку, где потом пользователь вводит значение, но я не знаю, как описать это в блок-схеме.

Answer (score 1):

Это два шага:

Шаг 1: действие - это прямоугольник.

В нем текст  (например): "Нажать на ячейку".

Шаг 2: данные - это параллелограмм (бывший прямоугольник, у которого крышу снесло  вправо:-).

В нем текст (например): "Ввести значение".

Картинки можно увидеть по адресу:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0#

Comment: Приколол меня вопрос, давненько я блок-схемы не вспоминал:-)